# Multiple Facebook Likes - Have to link to 1 Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook-like

Ive made a website which you can 'like' and this is linked to the Facebook Page.

Is it possible to have individual blog posts 'liked'? If so, how could I still link these to the Facebook Page in some manor?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give some example code and URLs? What do you mean by "linked to the Facebook Page"? Every Like Button can be assigned one URL of your choosing.

Comment: Say I had a blog and you could like individual blog posts, if I had a facebook page for the blog, would the blog post's likes relate to the page? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up Like Buttons for individual blog posts as long as each post has a distinct URL (which should be the case).

You cannot simultaneously Like a blog post and a Facebook page. A Like exists between one user and one Facebook object: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/

If you want to increase your Facebook page Like count, you can either direct people to the page itself or add a [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) to your blog.